# inetmgr crashes after adding IIS6 MetabaseCompatibility Role

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, iis-6, windows

I added the IIS6 MetabaseCompatibility Role to my Server 2008 but can no longer launch inetmgr:

```
IISMANAGER_CRASH

IIS Manager terminated unexpectedly.

Exception:System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.Web.Management.Host.Shell.ShellApplication.Initialize(Boolean localDevelopmentMode, Boolean resetPreferences)
   at Microsoft.Web.Management.Host.Shell.ShellApplication.Execute(Boolean localDevelopmentMode, Boolean resetPreferences, Boolean resetPreferencesNoLaunch)

Process:InetMgr
```

any ideas?
In the meantime, I uninstalled that role but I still don't have an inetmgr (mmc snapin doesn't work either).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like more than a IIS 6 metabase issue. Can you completly remove the role and then attempt to re-add the role and select IIS 6 metabase compatability during the re-add process

Answer (score 0):

I would love to have a look at CBS logfile from C:\Windows\Logs\CBS. There should be some entry for the failure and cause of crash. Let me know if you want me to have a look at the logs.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to try is from an elevated command prompt run:

```
Start Inetmgr.exe /reset
```

It could be that the preferences file has been corrupted so that command might help.